# How to put the green Add icon unconditionally on the Insert row

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView with a special row at the end to insert a new item. That works, but I want it to have the green plus icon without having to put the table view into editing mode. How can I do that?

I'd prefer not to create a button or bundle the image, if possible. Is there any way to do either or both of those things using only standard UITableView/UITableViewCell features?

Comment: It's a plain UITableViewCell.

Comment: do you mean you don't want the table view in editing mode, or you don't want the user to have to put it into editing mode?  would programmatically setting your table view to always be in edit mode serve your purpose?

Comment: @bshirley: Editing mode will be available to the user, but unless rows are tappable in editing mode, leaving editing turned on permanently is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

you want to set the `accessoryView` to the cell:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
  NSInteger nextValue;
  NSMutableArray *timeIntervals;
}


@implementation RootViewController


- (NSNumber *)nextValue {
  NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:nextValue];
  nextValue++;
  return n;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  nextValue = 1;
  timeIntervals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [timeIntervals addObject:[self nextValue]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [timeIntervals count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TimeIntervalCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
      [b addTarget:self action:@selector(addTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      cell.accessoryView = b;
    }

  NSNumber *number = [timeIntervals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.accessoryView.tag = indexPath.row;
  cell.textLabel.text = [number stringValue];
  cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"detail about this number";
  return cell;
}

- (void)addTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
  id cell = sender;
  while (cell != nil && [cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] == NO)
    cell = [cell superview];

  if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] sender was not in a cell", 
          NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return;
  }

  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
  NSInteger index = indexPath.row + 1; // insert after current cell
  [timeIntervals insertObject:[self nextValue] atIndex:index];
  NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
  [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSLog(@"[%@ %@] not implemented", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}


@end
```

(this is all the modified code to the Xcode 4.0.2 navigation app template)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement  your last cell as Custom Cell and add the green icon as per your choice.

See the tutorial to implement custom cell.

[iPhone Programming Tutorial: Part 6: Creating custom UITableViewCell Using Interface Builder UITableView](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/)

**Updated:**

Let's say **cell** is the instance of `UITabelViewCell`.

First create a button using your green icon.

```
UIButton myGreenIconButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myGreenIconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(GreenIconButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myGreenIconButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myGreenIconButton.tag = i;
myGreenIconButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myGreenIconButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 78, 15, 15);
```

Now add it as subview in your last `UITabelViewCell`.

```
[cell addSubview:myGreenIconButton];
```

Implement `GreenIconButtonClicked:` method to receive the click evrnt on you add green icon button

```
-(void) GreenIconButtonClicked:(id) sender
{

}
```

Comment: @Peter Hosey: you could add an green icon bundle with `UIButton` in your `UITabelView` as `subview`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way I've found to do this is to set the cell's image, which means you have to handle the image files yourself instead of having UIKit load them for you. I recommend using the [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) to get the image.